# Avoiding exposing details of a compiled C module

Tags: c, module

I created module `a.h` and `a.c`. How can I create a compiled encapsulated module from it (without adding `a.c` for each project, without exposing `a.h` implementation)?

I work with Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks

Comment: If your module's entrypoints (the functions you want to call from the outside) are declared in `a.h`, you're going to have to expose  the header. That's the purpose of headers. Then perhaps by following [a walkthrough on creating a static library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @unwind points out, you will have to expose, at the very least, those types and functions that you want the user to use.

Note, however, that if the user does not need to know the internals of a given type, you just give the user opaque types/pointers/handles.

In other words:

```
typedef struct Opaque Opaque;

Opaque * create(void);
void run(Opaque * handle);
void destroy(Opaque * handle);
```

Or even just:

```
void * create(void);
void apply(void * handle);
void destroy(void * handle);
```